# Animating menu icon in css

Tags: css, animation

I've been trying to animate this icon but not sure what is the practical way to do it.

Its basically a 3 lines rotate to create an arrow when you click it a menu will expand from the arrow direction  see icon --> [The Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZHOr.gif)

I managed to code it but one of the lines is not behaving like the way I want it to, I tried playing with transform-origin but it didn't work

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-box: view-box;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu-wrapper:hover .top {
  transform: translateY(12.5px);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: inherit;
}

.menu-wrapper:hover .middle {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="line top"></div>
  <div class="line middle"></div>
  <div class="line bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your html and css

Comment: Where is the icon? Umm.... An invisible icon can't  be animated.

Comment: For some reason, it wasn't showing now it is 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZHOr.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember to use `position:relative` when you are using `position:absolute;`

Here you go.

```css
*{transition:all .3s ease-out, all .3s ease-in;}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  /*background-color: green;*/
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  transform-box: view-box;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu-wrapper:hover .top {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: inherit;
  left: -12.5px;
  top: 12px;
}

.menu-wrapper:hover .middle {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="line top"></div>
  <div class="line middle"></div>
  <div class="line bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Also a codepen to play around: https://codepen.io/Ev1tw1n/pen/wQNWeq

Comment: It worked!! but still, there's something odd when I hover out the top line moves to the original position and then rotates to 0 deg who can I make it rotate first and then moves to the original position

Comment: Yeah it will go outside because, the line is rotating in its original place i.e., in the center. So we have to move that to the left.

Comment: @Hussoda you need to set `left: 0;` in .top first